# Incorrect result using Geometry.reverse() for XYM coordinates

Tags: java, postgis, jts, hibernate-spatial

We are using `jts-core` (`org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:jar:1.19.0`) together with `hibernate-spatial` (`org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:jar:5.6.10.Final:compile`) to retrieve geometries with measured dimensions from a PostGis (`14.3`) database.

The query looks something like this:

```
Geometry geometry = (Geometry) entityManager
    .createNativeQuery("SELECT st_locatebetween(geom, :p1, :p2) as geom FROM GEOMS WHERE id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .setParameter("p1", p1)
    .setParameter("p2", p2)
    .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
    .addScalar("geom", new JTSGeometryType(INSTANCE_WKB_2))
    .getSingleResult();
```

This query works fine to retrieve a geometry, returning XYM coordinates.  However, when we try to reverse the geometry using `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry#reverse`, the M-coordinates get lost.  All coordinates, except for the middle one, have a `NaN` value for `m`.

When trying this via a simple unit test using an array of `org.locationtech.jts.geom.CoordinateXYM`'s this works fine.  When debugging the query, it seems to be using `org.geolatte.geom.PackedPositionSequence` which returns an incorrect reversed array.

Are we doing something wrong?  Or is this a bug?

If we try doing this with `org.geolatte.geom.Geometry` directly we seem to get the same problem:

```
Geometry geometry = JTS.to(Wkt.fromWkt("LINESTRING M (1 1 1, 2 2 2, 3 3 3)"));

stream(geometry.getCoordinates()).forEach(System.out::println);
stream(geometry.reverse().getCoordinates()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

gives below output:

```
(1.0, 1.0 m=1.0)
(2.0, 2.0 m=2.0)
(3.0, 3.0 m=3.0)

(3.0, 3.0 m=NaN)
(2.0, 2.0 m=2.0)
(1.0, 1.0 m=NaN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. There is a mismatch between JTS's `reverse()` and the `org.geolatte.geom.PackedCoordinateSequence`. The `CoordinateSequence` doesn't return the correct value for the M- coordinate.

I've created [an issue](https://github.com/GeoLatte/geolatte-geom/issues/155) for this in the geolatte-geom project.

In the mean time you could use as a workaround a XYZM geometry with Z-coordinates set to 0.0. Then the mismatch disappears and reverse will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks!  As I workaround I did something similar already which seems to do the trick too: `geometryFactory.createLineString(geometry.getCoordinates()).reverse()`.